# Convert 'usual' regex into xsd-regex

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to convert a regex into a regex that can be used in a xsd-schema but somehow there is still an error in my schema.

The original regex is `%^[^"'\\&=<>*]*$` and it is working fine.
As I found out, `^` and `$` are complicated in xsd as they are not implemented.
The quotation `"` is difficult as well. But it should be possible to use `&quot;` instead

So when I set up my pattern like this

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="%[&quot;'\\&=<>*]*"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

which is not what I want, but it's a start, the result is `StartTag: invalid element name`

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Is there maybe a good instruction how to translate a usual regex into a regex that can be used in a xsd-schema?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `&` as `&amp;` and `<` as `&lt;`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I managed to form a valid pattern. Last things I struggle with are the caret and `$` sign

Comment: finaly I found out, xsd-regex ist anchored at both ends automaticaly. So the final expression is `<xs:pattern value="[^&quot;\\&amp;=&lt;&gt;\*]*"/>`